# Pagination with search for all pagination links in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

We made search with pagination but its working only on first page, when I click on second page in pagination its not working. I was tried to resolved this issue with creating session of search keyword but that not working properly.
Please provide good solution for this.

**Controller code:**

```
    function xyz(){
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/rainbow/admin/postList/xyz";
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->post_model->list_count();
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

    $data['lists']=$this->post_model->listing($config["per_page"], $page);
    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view('listing/listing_post',$data);
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
```

}

**Model Code:**

```
function search_listing($limit, $start)
{
    if(isset($this->input->get('search')))
    {
        $this->db->like('post_name',$this->input->get('search'))
    }
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $query=$this->db->get('blog');
    return $query->result();
}
```

**We applied Temporary DataTable Search Jquery:**  https://www.datatables.net/examples/

Comment: What is the error you get? Also, always is better to provide some code

Comment: I have already apply get variable with $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE; but on second link GET variable will be null

Answer (score 1):

Use CodeIgniter Pagination Library with

$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;

and pass your search element as query string.

then your URL would be like:
http://localhost/project/controller/function?var=val&var1=val1&per_page=10

You can get values of var, var1 & per_page by:
$this->input->get('var')
$this->input->get('var1')
$this->input->get('per_page')

Answer (score 0):

First modify your controller as bellow

```
function xyz()
 {
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/rainbow/admin/postList/xyz";
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$config['total_rows'] = $this->post_model->list_count();
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

$data['lists']=$this->post_model->listing($config["per_page"], $page);
$this->load->view('includes/header');
$this->load->view('listing/listing_post',$data);
$this->load->view('includes/footer');
 }
```

as I have seen your base url and find that uri segment three is your controller function xyz and hence pagination is not working.